# correct sql statement,using in and select

Tags: sql

```
select *
from at_production_scan_det 
where scanvalue in
   (SELECT relatedcontainer 
    from label_automotive 
    where labelnumber = '122208467')
```

Is this statement correct? It seems to display no values, even though the value with that label number is present in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The statement seems correct. Can you share your data?

Comment: Is a the value of `relatedcontainer` in table `at_production_scan_det ` column `scanvalue ` can you show the sample data?

Comment: If the subselect shows a value, but the select doesn't, then it means that the values `relatedcontainer` returns, are never equal to `scanvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems correct.

however for it to return any result at all, the conditions should be true.
That is, your query;

```
SELECT relatedcontainer 
from label_automotive 
where labelnumber = '122208467'
```

Should be returning values, which correspond to the `scanvalue` field of the table `at_production_scan_det`.
For example if the 1st query return 10, 11, 12, the `IN` clause will act like an `OR` statement as below;

```
select *
from at_production_scan_det 
where (scanvalue = 10 OR scanvalue = 11 OR scanvalue = 12)
```